# How to get additional Account Info tab in ADUC with Taskpads

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-7, user-accounts

as a part of delegating tasks to admins , we require to enable Additional Account tab(which shows, last password reset, SID , GUID last logon/Logoff etc)  in ADUC when user properties are viewed. How to enable it on all workstations, is it a AD schemachange? or a seperate version of DSA.MSC is needed? please do let me know how it can be implemented.

Answer (score 1):

You want AcctInfo.dll from the [Account Lockout and Management Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=18465). Copy AcctInfo.dll to system32 and run the following command:

> regsvr32 %systemroot%\system32\acctinfo.dll

As an alternative, you may try using the Active Directory Administrative Center (ADAC).

Answer (score 0):

You should be using Active Directory Administrative Center (ADAC).[image]

This has a "More information" at the bottom when you open a AD Object where you find

- Logon
- Logoff
- SID
- GUID
- Password Expiry
- Password Last set
- And more